# Фиолетовые пиксели в ряду картинок-ссылок

Tags: html, css

Вообщем, сделал я несколько ссылок-картинок на соцсети для сайта. Всё бы ничего, но в пробелах между картинками появились странные, фиолетовые черточки. Понятия не имею, с чем это связано. Могу лишь сказать, что если их рассположть в вертикальную строку, то черточки пропадают. Помогите, пожалуйста, кто знает, с чем это связано!
[image]

```
<p id="Social">Social</p>
    <a href="https://vk.com/id158092641"> <img class="social_img" src="img/Facebook_logo.png"> </a> 
    <a href="https://vk.com/id158092641"> <img class="social_img" src="img/Twitter_logo.png"> </a>
    <a href="https://vk.com/id158092641"> <img class="social_img" src="img/Google_logo.png"> </a>
    <a href="https://vk.com/id158092641"> <img class="social_img" src="img/YouTube_logo.png"> </a>
```

Comment: Border, подчёркивание, цвет. Проверь всех родителей

Comment: Лучше всего, если у вас получится выделить ваш код в [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в самих ссылках. По стандарту, у ссылок имеется подчёркивание. Что бы его убрать, добавьте к ссылке `text_decoration: none;`

```html
<p>С подчёриванием</p>
<a href="">Ссылка</a>
<p>Без подчёривания</p>
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Это сработало, Спасибо! Ты мне очень помог!